# hover effect shows background color instead of .jpeg in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, hover, effect

I am having issues with a css hover effect in Firefox, it only shows grey boxes but when the thumbnail is hovered over it shows the .jpeg image and text of the project. In google chrome there are no grey boxes just the .jpeg's to each thumbnail and when hovered over the text appears. I have attached a link to my website, please view in firefox for issue and google chrome to see the effect functioning properly.

http://www.jacobdelaneydesign.com/

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not your web site which will change or disappear soon helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: I think you should wash your CSS out with soap before posting a question with those obscenities in it. I don't know what a mod will do with your question.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for the advice I will make sure I post my markup next time I have an issue rather than the web address. You are quite right about the title of my css, a younger me with little patience is responsible and will make sure in future my code / file names are named correctly. I am sorry if I may have offended anyone.

Comment: So why aren't you able to edit all that now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put:

```
.hovereffect a, 
.hovereffect p {
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, you have been a great help :)

Comment: you're welcome :3

Answer (score 1):

`opacity: 0;` in `thisfuckingcss.css:111` breaks firefox experience. I'm not sure why its initially was set to 0, but `opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=1);` looks good to me. You can continue investigation from here if you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice, my problem is now fixed :)

Comment: @JacobDelaney yw, can you please mark answer as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost 100% because of whatever code you used that isn't compatible with Firefox.

Please take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions).

Many good CSS stylesheets get destroyed because their owners fail to notice cross-browser compatibility, and instead get frustrated about it.

Have a look at the website I linked, then prefix the appropriate (and needed) options with the `-moz` prefix.

Comment: Thank you for the link I have a better understanding when it comes to writing code for cross-browser compatibility.